# starting android avd fails, saying it can't find emulator, but it exists

Tags: 12.04, android

I've asked this question both on StackOverflow and the Android Dev forum, but neither got a single reply as of yet.  Perhaps a direct focus on Ubuntu might get some results.

I've installed the SDK on Ubuntu 12.0.4. I started up the SDK manager and updated several packages.

I ran the avd manager and tried to create an avd, but it just failed with no information.

I then tried to create the avd from the command line, using the same information I tried to use from the gui, and it worked.

When I tried to start that AVD, it failed with (some strings elided):

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "<myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

This is what I see when I look for this file:

```
$ ls -lt <myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
-rwxrwxr-x 1 <me> <me> 24828 May 25 08:20 <myhome>/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator*
```

As you can see, the path it's looking for DOES exist.

What's going on here?

From one of the responses:

```
$ file ~/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
~/apps/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
$ 
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x214a38d0db472db559f0dabf0ae97f82fea83e03, stripped
$ uname -a
Linux ... 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So, it looks like that might be the problem, but I don't see a 64-bit Android SDK distro.  Am I going to have to give up on the 64-bit Ubuntu if I want to use the Android SDK on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the 32 bits SDK on a 64 bits host, or vice versa?

If you are on 64bit you will need to install the `ia32-libs` package.

Comment: This was the issue that led me to the solution. I never looked at the installation instructions for the SDK.  I had installed it on Windows (32-bit) before, and didn't realize it required an extra step for 64-bit Ubuntu.  It required installing the ia32-libs package.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need install packages any more!

In directory tools, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is `Linux Mint 16 amd64`! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```